# With grunt, is there a way to simplify a files option (here handlebars task)

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I just started using grunt, and I search a way to declare files option more dynamically

my config is

```
  handlebars: {        
      compile: {
          options: {   
              namespace: Handlebars.Template',                    
              files: {
                  "public/media/js/module1/precompiledTemplates.js": "public/media/js/module1/templates/*.hbs",
                  "public/media/js/module2/precompiledTemplates.js": "public/media/js/module2/templates/*.hbs  ",
                  "public/media/js/module3/precompiledTemplates.js": "public/media/js/module3/templates/*.hbs  "
              }
  },
```

I've got lots of modules, is there a way to declare something like that ?

```
              files: {
                  "public/media/js/$1/precompiledTemplates.js": "public/media/js/(*.)/templates/*.hbs"                    
              }
```

I took a look [at this](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically)  , but i do not find the right way to manage this "problem".

Comment: Not really a way to do that as simply as you have it because the `files` option isn't a full regex, just a globbing pattern. You may need to write a [custom task](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks) if you want to use these options dynamically like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution based on the previous comment :

You must have a normal configuration about handlebars.compile  (or the plugin used). And add a custom task and build files object in javascript.

```
grunt.registerTask('hbs_compile', 'Your custom task', function() {
    var myFiles = {};

    // ... here you build your myFiles object, see grunt.file api ...
    // in my case :
    grunt.file.expand('my/modules/path/*').forEach(function (basePath) {
        myFiles[basePath + '/precompiledTemplates.js'] = basePath + '/templates/*.hbs'
    })
    // and you overide the configuration with your object
    grunt.config.set('handlebars.compile.files', myFiles);
    grunt.task.run('handlebars:compile');
});
```

Now, can you run in CLI :

```
$ grunt hbs_compile
```

and add modules less reconfigure grunt.